# Looping through result set MongoDB 3

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# Application that is supposed to read and write to a MongoDB 3 Database. Unfortunately it seems that with MongoDB 3 a lot of the namespaces and Methods have changed, so it has been a bit challenging.

Here is the code that I have:

```
        string connectionString = Settings.Default.MongoConnectionString;
        string databaseName = Settings.Default.MongoDatabaseName;

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var db = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);

        IMongoCollection<Post> collection = db.GetCollection<Post>("post");

        foreach (var post in collection.FindAll())
        {
            // Display to the user
        }
```

For some reason the "MongoCollection" class no longer exists. How can one loop through the returned results with the new version of MongoDB?

I am getting the following error:

> 'IMongoCollection' does not contain a definition for 'FindAll' and no extension method 'FindAll' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoCollection' could be found

Does anyone know the correct way to loop through the collection with the new version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New C# Driver (2.0) is totally async. In order to enumerate all documents in collection you should pass empty filter and use [`ToListAsync()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursorExtensions_ToListAsync__1.htm)

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Empty;
foreach(var post in collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result)
   // display
```

You can also use lambda instead of empty filter:

```
collection.Find(p => true).ToListAsync()
```

And of course instead of blocking you can create [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) method with awaiting of documents:

```
private async Task YourMethod()
{
    // ...
    var posts = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    foreach(var post in posts)
       // display
}
```

Recommended reading: [Introducing the 2.0 .NET Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver?jmp=docs&_ga=1.35690976.1557224716.1439727460)

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey. Both suggestion worked beautifully.

Comment: What if your collection is 10 millions items ? would it allocate a list with that number of documents ? If yes is there a away to avoid this ?

Comment: Using `AsQueryable()` seems to be the solution : 
`foreach(var item in collection.AsQueryable())` works like a charm even if collection contains many items.